# How to use single "with" context manager in python for an unknown number of variables

Tags: python, contextmanager

My problem looks like the following:

```
list = [1,2,3] #unknown length

with (item for item in list):
    ...
```

I know python 3.10 supports using a tuple in the context manager but I'm not able to use that version.

Comment: Python 3.10 doesn't support tuples. It supports parenthesizing a comma-separated list of context managers simply to avoid the need for explicit line continuation.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad I saw that in another question.

Comment: I'm assuming `list` is supposed to be a list of context managers, not `int`s?

Comment: Yes I just meant context manager 1,2,3 ...

Comment: Yes, I need to enter all at once. They are nested plates in pyro and that's how they have it set up.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an arbitrary list of context managers, you can use an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to enter each one dynamically.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

cm_list = [...]


with ExitStack() as es:
    for cm in cm_list:
        es.enter_context(cm)

    ...
```

The first context manager to be entered will be the last to exit, and the last to enter will be the first to exit, consistent with the idea that an `ExitStack` is, in fact, a stack of context managers.